How to exclude specific tags (like versioning tags) from Swagger-UI?
I'm working on a Golang project where I use Swagger-UI to render my OpenAPI spec file. My API has tags like resource, project, and v1 (for versioning). I want to hide specific tags (such as the v1 tag) from being displayed in the Swagger-UI, while still showing the relevant resource-related tags.
I've tried using a custom plugin in Swagger-UI to filter out the spec tags, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Here's the custom plugin I used:
const TagFilterPlugin = () => {
  return {
    wrapSelectors: {
      tagDetails: (originalSelector) => (state, system) => {
        const allTags = originalSelector(state, system);
        return allTags.filter(tag => tag.get('name') !== 'v1');
      },
    },
  };
};

SwaggerUI({
  url: "swagger.json",
  dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
  plugins: [
    SwaggerUI.plugins.DownloadUrl,
    TagFilterPlugin
  ]
});

This doesn't seem to hide the v1 tag in the UI.
How can I achieve this? Are there any recommended approaches or plugins for filtering tags in Swagger-UI?
